# How to remove nested collection from mongodb using mongoose?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

```
"notes" : [ 
        {
            "postedDate" : "26 May 2021",
            "_id" : ObjectId("60ae1e295bcc843910478f8b"),
            "note" : "Second Note",
            "replies" : [ 
                {
                    "repliedDate" : "26 May 2021",
                    "_id" : ObjectId("60ae1e365bcc843910478f8c"),
                    "reply" : "Reply content"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "postedDate" : "26 May 2021",
            "_id" : ObjectId("60ae0a95fa592734e41b6236"),
            "note" : "Hello",
            "replies" : [ 
                {
                    "repliedDate" : "26 May 2021",
                    "_id" : ObjectId("60ae0a9afa592734e41b6237"),
                    "reply" : "Hi"
                }, 
                {
                    "repliedDate" : "26 May 2021",
                    "_id" : ObjectId("60ae1ab15bcc843910478f88"),
                    "reply" : "new reply"
                }, 
                {
                    "repliedDate" : "26 May 2021",
                    "_id" : ObjectId("60ae1b085bcc843910478f89"),
                    "reply" : "Hie"
                }, 
                {
                    "repliedDate" : "26 May 2021",
                    "_id" : ObjectId("60ae1b185bcc843910478f8a"),
                    "reply" : "world"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

I have a notes collection and inside there are individual notes and each notes have replies. I want to remove the individual reply from the note under notes collection. I've used pull before for the same job but I don't know how to implement it if the collection in nested on two levels.

Comment: Does the answer help you?

Comment: It worked perfectly fine, thanks alot for the help

Comment: You are wolcome to SO. Please have a [Tour](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `update` with `arrayFilter`

```
db.collection.update({},
{
  "$pull": {
    "notes.$[n].replies": {
      "_id": "60ae1e365bcc843910478f8c"
    }
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "n._id": "60ae1e295bcc843910478f8b"
    }
  ]
})
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/u6qw3GhKbBm)**